# Column named 'row_number' gives error, SQLAlchemy, MariaDB

Tags: sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have a table that includes an int column named `row_number`. This worked fine until I upgraded Debian from 11 to 12 which upgraded MariaDB from 10.5 to 10.11.

I now get errors when using SQLAlchemy.

I've tracked down where the error occurs. With 10.11, this statement gives an error:

`UPDATE kae SET row_number=12 WHERE id=1`

*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'row_number=12 WHERE id=1' at line 1*

If I put backticks around the column name the update runs without error.

Can I force SQLAlchemy to backtick-quote that column name every time?

Is there a better fix than having to edit all occurrences of row_number in my code?

Comment: According to the description of the error, it looks like your statement is different with respect to the one you've shared. Referencing "*'FROM 'kae' WHERE id=1 AND (row_number <> 12)'*". Your error is likely to be related to the fact that update statements have no `FROM` clause in MariaDB.

Comment: Apologies: I took that error from phpMyAdmin. I've updated the question with the error reported in the CLI.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue under SQLAlchemy 2.0.8. MariaDB 10.5 has no complaints with a column named `row_number`, but MariaDB 10.11 does. You may want to open a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues).

Comment: Is it possible that the window function with the same name [row_number](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) is causing a conflict ?

Comment: Can you include the version of sqlalchemy and whatever driver you are using to connect to mariadb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround and patch to SQLAlchemy here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9585

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `quote=True` on the `row_number` column: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.quote

This should cause the column to be quoted automatically.